# How can I search without knowing the field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have about 100k documents and they look something like this:

```
{
  "news": "abc",
  "createdAt": 1527786360574,
  "id": "fc554a1d-64f4-11e8-5a54-fbcd7712f7bf",
  "location": "東京都 Japan",
  "title": "Something happened",
  "url": "url-of-the-news",
  "userId": "fc515a1c-69g4-1ie8-9a54-ftcd775ff7bf",
  "username": "stevemao",
  "attributes": []
}
```

On the frontend there's only one text field and I use it to search for anything (including fuzziness).

EG: if the input is `"japan"` I'm expecting the document above to return. Same as `"abc"` since it's the news. If there's attributes I can search that too.

I don't know the field value for the search. How should I index the documents and what field should I specify when searching them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. You know the index but you don't know the field to search on. Prioir to version 6.0, you can use the `_all` field. See
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html